# Android Virtual Device Manager quit unexpectedly

Tags: android

When I try to run the android emulator using `android avd` and then clicking on `Start`, I get said error message.

Answer (score 1):

Start the emulator instead by using

```
emulator -avd emulator_device_name &
```

where you fill in `emulator_device_name` with the name of the emulator you see when you run `android avd`.

Comment: i like the way how you answer your own question instantly :-O and without a second of delay 0o

Comment: An answer. I hope it helps others.

Comment: Yeah, but that's probably a way to post an "article" here. I wanted to share some knowledge on a certain point, but couldn't find a way to do so, and in the metaStack I read that posting a question and answering it, is some kind of a workaround for this :-)

Comment: There is actually a button to ask and answer at the same time, to share your knowledge Q+A style. It appears to be encouraged. I've benefited from other people's Q+A's because they're easy to find.